# node.js on Windows frequently fails with 'EMFILE: too many open files'

Tags: node.js, windows, browserify

When using various tools on Windows, eg `browserify`, I frequently see:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\mike\Documents\myapp\node_modules\babel-polyfill\node_modules\core-js\package.json'
    at Error (native)
```

Unlike Linux, where maximum open files is a soft limit that chan be changed, it seems [EMFILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5814770t.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a hard limit in Windows.

How can I fix this?

**note**: I have solved the problem, but it took a week and I couldn't find anything on the internet when I searched, so I'm about to put the answer here for the next node-Windows person

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [graceful-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graceful-fs) module can be used to limit the amount of file IO, slowing things down a little but avoiding node crashes due to EMFILE.

```
// Monkey-patch real fs module, so all I/O uses graceful FS.
var fs = require('fs')
var gracefulFs = require('graceful-fs')
gracefulFs.gracefulify(fs)
```

Comment: It'd be nice if there's a way of fixing it without having to change the source code. More specifically, if you use an external library you can end up having this issue without the ability to change the source code (at least not easily).

Comment: @carl-johan.blomqvist node modules are singletons, so you can require and monkey patch `fs` before you load our third party module.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: @JuliusGoddard If it still crashes due to EMFILE (you haven't said this so I have to guess) make sure you're doing the monkey patching before loading any external modules. Better yet: swap from node for Windows to using Linux node on Windows via WSL